# UITextView delegate methods

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextview

I am trying to get delegate methods to work with UITextView, but it's not working for some reason.

I have declared in my viewController.h that it is a UITextViewDelegate

I am trying to get the following code to work to erase the default code "TEXT" when I tap on the textView.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if (myTextView.text == @"TEXT") {
        [myTextView setText:@""];
    }

    NSLog(@"did begin editing");
}
```

I expected to the text to be cleared and to see the NSLog print when I tap on the textView and the keyboard appears. Nothing at all happens

---

Using a text view by the way because I need to scale the view based on its content size and seems that the textView has a contentSize property, whit label and textField do not.

UPDATE:

I should have used:

```
if ([myTextView.text isEqualToString:@"TEXT"]) {
    [myTextView setText:@""]; }
```

[here is the project if you want to take a look.](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/UITextViewTest.zip)

Comment: Also, I updated my answer to correct your string comparison and changed the project.  Download the updated project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this method is missing from your **Test2ViewController.m** file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [myTextView setDelegate:self];
}
```

or you can connect the delegate in the *Interface Builder* as well, if you prefer that way better.

**UPDATE #1:**

add this method to you class for controlling the `return` key.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        NSLog(@"Return pressed, do whatever you like here");
        return NO; // or true, whetever you's like
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! One more question. Is it possible to have the return key make the textView resign first responder. There is no method as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Connect the delegate of the TextView in Interface Builder to the parent class.  I like to use the connection in IB rather than code it.  To me the less code to look at the better :).  Also - don't compare strings that way.  Use isEqualToString for string comparison:

```
if ([myTextView.text isEqualToString:@"TEXT"]) {
        [myTextView setText:@""];
}
```

[image: Connection Pic]

[Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/Test2_Fixed.zip) is the fixed project:

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a good solution in principle:

Set the UITextView's delegate to self and then make your own delegate - re-using the same name.  This allows you to intercept the delegate without anything looking different from the outside

```
@interface TTGTextView : UITextView<UITextViewDelegate>// UIPlaceHolderTextView
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITextViewDelegate> delegate;
@synthesize delegate = realDelegate;
```

Then go ahead and intercept the methods.  Note that you need to cover all of them, otherwise they won't react the "real" delegate

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidBeginEditing:)])
    [realDelegate textViewDidBeginEditing:textView];
  /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
}
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidChange:)])
    [realDelegate textViewDidChange:textView];
  /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
}
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidChangeSelection:)])
    [realDelegate textViewDidChangeSelection:textView];
  /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
}
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidEndEditing:)])
    [realDelegate textViewDidEndEditing:textView];
  /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)])
    return [realDelegate textView:self shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text];
  return YES;
}
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:)])
    return [realDelegate textView:self shouldInteractWithURL:URL inRange:characterRange];
  return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)textAttachment inRange:(NSRange)range
{
  if ([realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textView:shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:inRange:)])
    return [realDelegate textView:textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:textAttachment inRange:range];
  return YES;
}
```

Some of the methods fire correctly, others don't fire for me at all but immediately appear for the "real" delegate.  But this is a starting point.  I guess a more solid and general way would be to make some kind of multiplexer - make it a UITableViewDelegate which holds an array of delegates to fire to.

Answer (score 1):

Your UITextview needs to be told where its delegate methods lies...

If you add it via interface builder then simply connect the delegates

or if via code

```
[yourTextViewOutlet setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Deponds on your View. 
if you use TextField, you should be used UITextFieldDelegate in .header file as a delegate just like show below.

```
@interface ExamPageViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and than we can be used UITextFieldDelegate methods. You can see;

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.questionAnswerTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"Sorunun cevabını buraya yazınız!"]) {
        textField.text = @"";
    }
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textField.text = @"Sorunun cevabını buraya yazınız!";
    }
}
```

Otherwise you should be used UITextViewDelegate as a delegate like below code snippet.

```
@interface ExamPageViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

and than we can be used these delegate methods in .m file

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textField {
    [self.questionAnswerTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField {

    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"Sorunun cevabını buraya yazınız!"]) {
        textField.text = @"";
    }
}


- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textField {
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textField.text = @"Sorunun cevabını buraya yazınız!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 4,5***

write this extension at the bottom of your controller. it can be use to show and hide placeholder in textView.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView == yourTxtView {
            txtNote.text = ""
            txtNote.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView == yourTxtView {
            txtNote.text = "Note:"
            txtNote.textColor = .gray
        }
    }
}
```